# Why is Puma so slow in WSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Puma in Windows Subsystem for Linux, installing it was a breeze and it worked right away but serving static files is horribly slow. It takes more than 8 seconds to serve them:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on or how to fix it? The app itself is running at a good speed.

I run puma by executing:

```
rails s Puma
```

Other than adding the gem to my Gemfile, I haven't made any particular configuration for Puma.

Comment: This is hard to tell from just a screenshot. You might want to share the configuration file and how you invoke Puma so that others might have a chance to find what is happening.

Comment: @HolgerJust I updated the question. What configuration would you like me to share with you?

Comment: @Pablo did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Note: starting June 2019, [WSL 2 is coming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56012225/6309), and brings considerable performance improvements.

Answer (score 2):

According to [WSL I/O performance issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/873) , it seem to be the root cause is WSL itself at the moment. Hope Microsoft will improve WSL asap.

Webrick work fine in WSL, when in develop environment, you can run `rails s webrick` to start quick webrick server

Comment: Wow. That is a lot faster with Webrick. Thanks! Was feeling like I'd have to dust out the ole ubuntu laptop for dev work again.

Answer (score 2):

I found that rails was slow startup because i was running it on ntfs drive /mnt/c etc.

When running rails in WSL which you can get to with cd ~ in wsl. My speed problems were resolved.

Comment: the problem is about serving files.. not a boot.

Comment: I ran into this exact issue with serving static files.  I cloned my repository to the home directory (~) and it's acceptable (full refresh in about 15 seconds compared to timing out after 2 minutes under /mnt/c/).  Also, it's worth noting that doing this, you can access the files in windows using //wsl$/ "network" location.